# Crontab not running a binary file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, admin, cron

My crontab file has following:

`SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/bin/run1.sh`

`run1.sh` has

`#!/bin/bash`
`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
cd /root/madhu_test/bpstest/
touch bhasina.txt
./bpsh-linux-x86-3.1 appTest_saurav.tcl apptest.ini.96.70.NSSTuned NSS-Tuned
./bpsh-linux-x86-3.1 appTest_saurav.tcl apptest.ini.96.70.S2C CriMajMinS2C`

But crontab is unable to run the binary file `bpsh-linux-x86-3.1`. However touch works.

Comment: Does script `/root/bin/run1.sh` have executable bit? Are you talking about `/etc/crontab` file, right? Try to modify redirect stderr to stdout and check is there any errors (`* * * * * /bin/bash /root/bin/run1.sh 2>&1`).

Comment: If I understand correctly, cron run the run1.sh (except bpsh-linux.... parts). Check your /var/log/cron.log... (maybe use absolte path, not relative)

Comment: @SlavaSemushin: `/etc/crontab` is a system crontab file. It has a different format, with an added 6th field specifying a user name. The crontab file in the question is not a system crontab.

Comment: Do you really have `PATH=...` on the same line as `#!/bin/bash`? Can you run `run1.sh` from the command line?

Comment: touch works, that is fine! Is bpsh-linux-x86-3.1 started when you call run1.sh from the commandline? Does it ask any questions that cron can't answer?